# Выставление информации по центру для все экранов

Tags: php

Так как у всех экраны разные, нужно это:

```
<div style='width:250px;border:0px solid black;margin-center: 0%;'>
  <div align="left" style='center:0px;width:100%;background-color:green;'><?php  echo "{$row['all_life']}"; echo "/{$row['life']}";  ?></div>

<div style='width:250px;border:0px solid black;margin-center: 0%;'>
  <div align="left" style='center:0px;width:100%;background-color:blue;'><?php echo "{$row['exp']}"; } ?></div>
```

Выставить по центру **для всех экранов**, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

центр

```
<center>Текст</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<div style='width:250px;border:0px solid black;margin: 0px auto;'>`